# How to count the amount of each object in an array list (Java)?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a beginner in Java so this may be a very basic question but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.

I would like to know how do you count the amount of each object in an array list, where the items are not named in the code?

I have 2 classes, one to simulate a vending machine, and the other representing the snacks. The constructor of the snacks class initiates the snack type as a string type as so:

```
public TypeOfSnack(String SnkType)
```

Then in the vending machine class these can be added onto the arraylist. The field for this is:

```
private ArrayList<TypeOfSnack> snacks;
```

I know to get the number of snacks in the array list by doing snacks.size(); But how do I return the amount of each type. So far I have done:

```
public int countSnacks(String SnkType)
    {
        return packets.size();
    }
```

Which is just given me the total amount rather than the one passed through the method.

Thanks

Comment: How would you do it in any other progamming language? How would you do it if you literally had a box of snacks and were asked to count the number of Mars bars?

Comment: You say you want to return the number of snacks from each type but your function returns int. Maybe start from a function that gets a snack and checks how much of it there is in the machine. GL

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the actual list to a unique item list and after that, you could use the method [Collections.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) to know how many time the same element appears in the list.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(5);

    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

    for(Integer unique : new HashSet<>(numbers)) {
        result.put(unique, Collections.frequency(numbers, unique));
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

> {2=1, 3=1, 5=6}

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you want to store the number of each snack in an ArrayList.
An ArrayList is not suitable for this problem, you should use HashMap.
Maybe something like the following code:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> snacks = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
snacks.put("Chips", 5);
snacks.put("Fried", 2);
```

To get the number of a snack:

```
int numberOfChips = snacks.get("Chips");
```

Or if you want to do it your way:

```
public int getNumberOf(String snackType) {
    int value = 0;
    for(TypeOfSnack s : snacks) {
        if(s.getType().equals(snackType)) { 
            value++;
        }
    }
}
```